# joining same table twice in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand what's the purpose of the join in this query.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT o.order_id 
FROM 
    `order` o, 
    `order_product` as op 
LEFT JOIN `provider_order_product_status_history` as popsh 
    on op.order_product_id = popsh.order_product_id 
LEFT JOIN  `provider_order_product_status_history` as popsh2 
    ON popsh.order_product_id = popsh2.order_product_id 
        AND popsh.provider_order_product_status_history_id < 
               popsh2.provider_order_product_status_history_id 
WHERE 
    o.order_id = op.order_id 
    AND popsh2.last_updated IS NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

What bothering me is that provider_order_product_status_history has joined 2 times and I'm not sure the purpose of it. Highly appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a technique to retrieve the latest order status.

Because of

```
AND popsh.provider_order_product_status_history_id < popsh2.provider_order_product_status_history_id
```

and

```
AND popsh2.last_updated IS NULL
```

Only those order status that doesn't have any newer status are returned.

For a minimum set example, consider the following status history table:

```
id  status order_id last_updated
--------------------------------
1   A      X        1:00
2   B      X        2:00
```

The self join will result in:

```
id  status order_id last_updated    id  status order_id last_updated
--------------------------------    --------------------------------
1   A      X        1:00            2   B      X        2:00
2   B      X        2:00                NULL   NULL     NULL
```

The first row will be filtered out by the `IS NULL` condition, leaving only the second raw, which is the latest one.

For a 3-row case the self join result will be:

```
id  status order_id last_updated    id  status order_id last_updated
--------------------------------    --------------------------------
1   A      X        1:00            2   B      X        2:00
1   A      X        1:00            3   C      X        3:00
2   B      X        2:00            3   C      X        3:00
3   C      X        3:00                NULL   NULL     NULL
```

And only the last one will pass the `IS NULL` condition, leaving the latest one again.

It looks like an unnecessarily complicated way to do the job, but it actually works quite well as RDBMS engines do joins very efficiently.

BTW, as the query retrieves only order_id, the query is not useful as it is. I guess the OP omitted other fields in the select clause. It should be something like `SELECT o.order_id, popsh.* FROM ...`

Comment: Great answer!. Thanks for explaining the technique. Yes, I just put only the important parts of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you have an error:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT o.order_id 
FROM 
    `order` o, 
    `order_product` as op 
LEFT JOIN `provider_order_product_status_history` as popsh 
    on op.order_product_id = popshs.order_product_id 
  ** YOU HAVE EXCESS 's' HERE     ^
LEFT JOIN  `provider_order_product_status_history` as popsh2 
    ON popsh.order_product_id = popsh2.order_product_id 
        AND popsh.provider_order_product_status_history_id < popsh2.provider_order_product_status_history_id 
WHERE 
    o.order_id = op.order_id 
    AND popsh2.last_updated IS NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

Based from my analysis, the query is *trying* to extract the **first o.order_id or first entry** (based on `provider_order_product_status_history.provider_order_product_status_history_id`) of the `provider_order_product_status_history`. However, *the joins semantic used in this query is not recomendable.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error and answering, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both joins being an inner-kind restrict resultset on conditions. It's like "gimme only values from table 1 that have corresponding row in table 2 on condition1 and at the same time a row in table2 on condition2".